# Constrain constructor argument type with class generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an object which I want to map into several other structures based on its keys. Each key-value should be considered separately, so I want to map object into array of entries, map entries into policy objects and apply them all. So my goal is to use this object like this:

```
type ValuesMap = {key1: Value1; key2: Value2; ...};
const valuesMap: ValuesMap = getValues();
const results = Object.entries(valuesMap).map(([key, value]) => policyFactory.createPolicy(key, value).apply());
```

For this to work I want to create an abstract policy class and factory for those policies:

```
type Key = keyof ValuesMap;
type Value<K extends Key> = ValuesMap[K];
abstract class Policy<K extends Key> {
  constructor(protected readonly value: Value<K>) {}
  abstract apply();
}

class ConcreteKey1Policy extends Policy<'key1'> {
  //constructor of this class shall accept only Value1 argument; ts should raise error when this class is constructed with other type
  apply() {/*...*/}
}

//...
class PolicyFactory {
  private readonly constructorMap: {
    [K in Key]: new (value: Value<K>) => Policy<K>;
  } = {
    key1: ConcreteKey1Policy;
    key2: ConcreteKey2Policy;
    //same for all considered keys of ValuesMap
  };

  createPolicy<K extends Key>(type: K, value: Value<K>): Policy<K> {
    return new this.constructorMap[type](value); //error1
    switch(type) {
      case 'key1':
        return new ConcreteKey1Policy(value); //error2
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

I tried 2 approaches for factory class, one with map of possible keys and constructors for them, another with switch for a `type` argument.

Both raise typescript errors:

- when I try to create object form constructor map I get the error: `type '"key1"' is not assignable to type 'K'. '"key1"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Key'`
- when I try switch, for every concrete policy creation I get the error: `Argument of type 'Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Key1'. Type 'Value2' is not assignable to type 'Value1'.`

I think I understand both of those errors, however, I have no idea how I can overcome them. I need to use generics in factory, so `value` type is tied to the type of `type`, but when I use `extends Key`, I create a constraint of any subtype of `Key` - but what I need is any type of the union `Key` and no other type. How can I create such constraint? Maybe there is a simpler way to achieve what I need here?

Comment: I think I don't get the question, between the code as it is seems to be working: [playground](https://t.ly/xJnx)

Comment: Please make sure your code is a [mre] that demonstrates the issue when we paste it into our IDEs.  Right now I'm not seeing the errors you're talking about.

Comment: Well, it seems it's fixed in a new typescript version - my project uses 4.4.4, in the playground it works from 4.6.4 up. I will update TS in my project today and confirm that it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be fixed in newer typescript version. As you can see in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QIxQLxQN5QJYAmAXFAHZIC2ARhAE4A0ZcFEJAzsLXqQOZQC%20AWABQoSLEQoATJihUA9vIQQ4pEWOjxkENgFk4YWbgDWEEKhJaUqRqZBTLkiDP4BuEevDQA0mdl35ADMJbT0Dd1EvEJQAHm8oCAAPYAhSAjYoXxAAPlkrHX0wAG1vAF0IuCoOWjgAY2AoWoQ4NgyABSU8WpA4hOTU9MyzXOwRKEb5UmqkevlaAAowWnkU%20ogCKFoVAkmEECgANydHbTjsgEocIWFxyuq6hoMwPfnzkgP5QgjrkSaWjIAwpNalsUllUB0EF19kkUml2p1ujEAOR2VDIkZjKAAemxtUm01mtCgQSgwAAFngMn9WlA2OTEAgoHVahAwA1dvt8ug4LQeJRUsBXGSMvT5EgEBsalToHRlsSAO7k1JkynU5q0qkTKacGYpDYKvAUkkUuhkrxYp4vS64a4-YQ0wHA0EQLJSSHQvpwwYepGosxSDE4LG4-E62h6uYk4IUrWOukMhBMllsjmkPbRZzMvkC0hCkUJ8WSzZwGUJWjyqBKlWx9X-fDUgm6tYGo3kk3K4kaS1gZ4gV44AQie1hjiNYzoLCkCAKqBA0ggiBgswQxH93CEEg2JgsEgAIhaBECe4E5wio4atWMMinM7nzqXroDvv7gUQbAgZ48Do1CKh3QAMQeOZ9lGG4oCWPAjhSTZtk5bVCWAOZChIMDxnGEp8FIIYQFKEhp1neYjm0E5Ym8C5MFyF8zgicZ%20CMLFxjREh50XZdzBfehGKgOwHHvBcXTdF9uNxNhmGgQIo0ZBDCDodYeLMDJSXyMIwCxNxv3GRc4BSaj4lhAYMiybJ5g0EhvEYYiUFIiAzjeKA9MxcDxlBJBaGwgjVSpAA6C8IyJQoig0UoiKcL9wLtb8LygN8iX2W9ZxfIC4teCIRFipDaBAXyth0iAX3mPc0T3RgN2IKBt1IcT9yqlgT34cKMpAnKVF0tdCt4kqyQjT9XCAA) (thank you [@colinD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3797799/colind)), it works from version 4.6.4 up. I updated ts version in my project from 4.4.4 to the latest and now it works.